# What Is This Top Indicator View Called And Can You Use It?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-location

The screenshot below shows the top indicator view displayed while the Apple Map app is tracking user location and when you take a screen recording on your iOS device. What is this top indicator view called? Also, can we create and display this view from our own custom apps? For example, if my app is tracking user location, can I display a green version of this view while my app is running in background? If so, how do you access it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot affect what the user sees on the home screen (except to badge your icon).

If your app is tracking user location, the user is notified of that fact by the system; there is nothing for you to do. If you have Always authorization, it would be nice to set the location manager's `showsBackgroundLocationIndicator` to `true`, but that's all you can do.